# Robots.txt / How can I hide a single HTML tag from search engines?

Tags: html, seo, hide, robots.txt

I'm building a one-page portfolio that has a contact form/section at the bottom of it. Next to my form I have listed most services I can provide. This however creates to many key words of the same kind and thus I started to wonder how I could hide that section from search engines.

My first thought was using the robots.txt but if you have a better idea lemme know. Thanks

Comment: As far as  know the search engines aren't executing JavaScript when they crawl pages... just add the content with JavaScript.

Comment: Hm, this could work. How do you check your keyword density to confirm that your not over optimizing?

Comment: no it won't work... I recently watched a video of google which told me that they check JavaScript but if the file is external and you disallow access to it in the robots.txt they can't check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hide that content from the search engines what you will be doing is called "cloaking". Cloaking is serving different content to search engines then you do to users. This is black hat SEO and will **get you banned** if you do it.

FYI, there's no such things as "too many keywords". A page can rank for an unlimited amount of search terms. Plus on page content is just one of many ranking signals. So having all of your services listed is a *good thing*. If you remove them you're making your site less visible, not more.

Comment: Hey John, thanks for the reply. What I meant though is that I have used one keyword already a whole bunch on the same page and I don't want to get punished for over optimization. P.S. How do you check for that?

Comment: If your content makes sense to a human being it isn't over optimized. When keywords are stuffed into a page it is usually obvious and that's when things start to become "over optimized".

Comment: Thanks again mate, but then what does the term "keyword density" stand for if it's completely irrelevant?

Comment: Don't worry about keyword density. That's nothing to be concerned about. It's like chasing PageRank.

Comment: Do you happen to be able to point to that somewhere on Google's help files? Or at least somewhere close so I can read up on that? Thanks

Comment: You won't find any search engines specifically mention keyword density. If they use it they won't tell us about it or how much it affects things. But it's pretty clear search engines are way beyond keyword density in their algorithms. Not to mention it would probably take a human review before a site had issues due to it. It really does come down to whether it makes sense to humans or not.